# why is my copy constructor producing a segfault everytime i try to alter the object

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault, containers, copy-constructor

```
/* Copy constructor */
List(const List<value_type>& list)
{
    // for (iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it); 
    //   this->push_back(*it);
    // The commented part above is what I want it to do.
    std::cout << "empty = " << this->empty(); // no seg fault;
    std::cout << "size = " << this->size(); // also causes a seg fault
    this->push_back("string") // causes a seg fault
}
```

Trying to run this code gives my program a seg fault. It seems every time I try to change or alter (this) it just just throws a seg fault.

Also it says (this) is not empty (that seems to be the only one that doesn't throw a seg fault)

Here is the code for the methods called for further info. Hopefully someone here can give me some insight into what is happening here.

```
void insert(iterator position, const value_type& in)
{
    // If inserting at the front, just change the head to a new Node
    if (position == this->head) 
        this->head = new Node<value_type>(in);
    else
    {
        Node<value_type>* node = this->head;
        // iterate to the position of "position".
        for (; node->next != position.node; node = node->next);
        node->next = new Node<value_type>(in);
    }
    // This is here to put back all the old data into it's correct position.
    // I was having way too much with keeping the integrity of the data
    // while inserting into the middle of the list, so I created this little hack.
    for (iterator it = position; it != this->end(); ++it)
    {
            Node<value_type> *node = this->head;
            for (; node->next != NULL; node = node->next);
            node->next = new Node<value_type>(it.node->data);
    }
}

// Insert at end
void push_back(value_type in)
{
    this->insert(this->end(), in);
}

unsigned size()
{
    if (this->empty()) return 0;
    unsigned i = 0;
    for (iterator it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ++it, ++i);
    return i;
}

bool empty() const { return this->head == NULL; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out the problem almost immediately after I wrote this up.

All I had to do was first assign head to NULL

```
List(List<value_type>& list)
{
    this->head = NULL;

    for (iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
        this->push_back(*it);
}
```